# Альтернатива Array.prototype.find()

Tags: javascript, массивы, obj

Есть ли альтернатива методу `Array.prototype.find()` для объектов?

Comment: поиск по св-вам вы имеете ввиду? или что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  'test': { a: 1 },
  'test1': { a: 2 },
  'test2': { a: 3 },
  'test3': { a: 4 },
  'test4': { a: 5 },
}
const findKey = 'test';
const key = Object.keys(obj).find((element, index) => {
  return findKey === element;
});

console.log('Get object by KEY:', obj[key]);

const findValue = 2;
const value = Object.values(obj).find((element, index) => {
  return findValue === element.a;
});

console.log('Get object by VALUE:', value);
```

Для объектов можно использовать **Object** и использовать тот же поиск функцией **find()**